# Converting duplicates to new columns, getting ActiveX 429 runtime error?

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to convert duplicate rows to single row with extra columns:

[image]

I have this script, which was working just fine a month ago, but now getting a runtime 429 error on `Set dictRw = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")` line

```
Sub DoPivot()
Const ROW_COL As Long = 1
Const COL_COL As Long = 2
Const VAL_COL As Long = 3

Dim rngIn As Range, rngOut As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet, arr, dict, r As Long, vRow, vCol
Dim dictRw As Object, dictCol As Object
Set dictRw = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
Set dictCol = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set rngIn = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
arr = rngIn.Value
Set rngOut = ws.Range("F1")

rngOut.Value = arr(1, ROW_COL)
For r = 2 To UBound(arr, 1)
    vRow = CStr(arr(r, ROW_COL))
    vCol = CStr(arr(r, COL_COL))
    If Not dictRw.exists(vRow) Then  'new row ?
        dictRw.Add vRow, dictRw.Count + 1
        rngOut.Offset(dictRw(vRow)).Value = vRow
    End If
    If Not dictCol.exists(vCol) Then 'new column?
        dictCol.Add vCol, dictCol.Count + 1
        rngOut.Offset(0, dictCol(vCol)).Value = vCol
    End If
    'populate the value (note: not checking to see if the cell already has a value...)
    rngOut.Offset(dictRw(vRow), dictCol(vCol)).Value = arr(r, VAL_COL)
Next r
End Sub
```

Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: Antivirus blocking the Dictionary creation?

Comment: @TimWilliams no anti-virus software, but I am on Mac OSX, would that affect it? It was working on this computer just fine beforehand

Comment: I didn't know that scripting.dictionary ever worked on Mac....

Comment: @TimWilliams is there a way to change this code to omit scripting?

Comment: Yes you can use `Application.Match` on Col F to check if there's already a row for the name.

Comment: Or look at: https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Dictionary

Comment: @TimWilliams I tried doing this in power query by duplicating landowner column, selecting the duplicate and pivoting it, but it just ended up as a mess and didn't look like what I outlined up above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Match()`:

```vb
Sub DoPivot()
    Const ID_COL As Long = 1
    Const ACRE_COL As Long = 2
    Const PARCEL_COL As Long = 3
    
    Dim rngIn As Range, rngOut As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet, arr, r As Long
    Dim m As Variant, nextRow As Long, c As Range, maxcol As Long
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set rngIn = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    arr = rngIn.Value
    
    Set rngOut = ws.Range("F2")
    With rngOut.CurrentRegion
        If .Cells.CountLarge < ws.Cells.CountLarge Then .Clear   'clear previous?
    End With
    
    nextRow = rngOut.Row
    maxcol = 0
    rngOut.Value = arr(1, ID_COL)
    For r = 2 To UBound(arr, 1)
        m = Application.match(arr(r, ID_COL), rngOut.EntireColumn, 0)
        If IsError(m) Then  'new name?
            nextRow = nextRow + 1
            m = nextRow
            ws.Cells(nextRow, rngOut.Column).Value = arr(r, 1) 'add name
        End If
        'find next position on this row
        Set c = ws.Cells(m, ws.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1)
        c.Value = arr(r, ACRE_COL)
        With c.Offset(0, 1)
            .NumberFormat = "@"         'format as text before adding value
            .Value = arr(r, PARCEL_COL)
        End With
        If c.Column > maxcol Then 'need to add more headers?
            ws.Cells(rngOut.Row, c.Column).Resize(1, 2).Value = _
                      Array(arr(1, ACRE_COL), arr(1, PARCEL_COL))
            maxcol = c.Column
        End If
    Next r
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach using Power Query using the Table.Group function, and creating a `Record` out of each set of data:

*This approach ensures that columns do not have identical names as this is not allowed in a `Table`. Also it will adapt so you can have more than two parcels per landowner.*

[image]

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Landowner Name", type text}, {"Acres", type number}, {"Parcel ID", type text}}),
    
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Landowner Name"}, {
        {"Acres/Parcel",(t)=>let 
            FieldNames = List.Repeat({{"Acres","Parcel ID"}}, Table.RowCount(t)),
            Fields = List.Combine(List.Generate(
                ()=>[cn=FieldNames{0},idx=0],
                each [idx] < List.Count(FieldNames),
                each [cn= List.Transform(FieldNames{[idx]+1},(li)=> li & "." & Text.From([idx]+1)),        
                        idx=[idx]+1],
                each [cn])),
            Values = List.Combine(List.Zip({t[Acres],t[Parcel ID]}))
            in 
                Record.FromList(Values,Fields)}}),

    #"All Fields" = List.Distinct(List.Combine(List.Transform(#"Grouped Rows"[#"Acres/Parcel"], each Record.FieldNames(_)))),
    #"Expand Records" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Grouped Rows","Acres/Parcel",#"All Fields"),
    
    #"Type Data" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expand Records", List.Transform(
        Table.ColumnNames(#"Expand Records"), each if Text.StartsWith(_,"Acre") then {_, type number} else {_, type text}))
in
    #"Type Data"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the result if you want to try Power Query. The tricky bit is the `Table.AddColumn` steps.

[image]

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Grouped by Landowner" = Table.Group(Source, {"Landowner Name"}, {{"AllRows", each _, type table [Landowner Name=nullable text, Acres=nullable number, Parcel ID=nullable number]}}),
    #"Added Parcel ID" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped by Landowner", "Parcel ID", each [AllRows][Parcel ID]),
    #"Added Acres" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Parcel ID", "Acres", each [AllRows][Acres]),
    #"Removed AllRows" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Acres",{"AllRows"}),
    #"Extracted Parcel ID" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Removed AllRows", {"Parcel ID", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ","), type text}),
    #"Extracted Acres" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Extracted Parcel ID", {"Acres", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ","), type text}),
    #"Split Parcel" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Extracted Acres", "Parcel ID", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Parcel ID.1", "Parcel ID.2"}),
    #"Split Acres" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Split Parcel", "Acres", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Acres.1", "Acres.2"}),
    #"Demoted Headers" = Table.DemoteHeaders(#"Split Acres"),
    #"Transposed Table" = Table.Transpose(#"Demoted Headers"),
    #"Split headers" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Transposed Table", "Column1", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(".", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Column1.1", "Column1.2"}),
    #"Sorted headers" = Table.Sort(#"Split headers",{{"Column1.2", Order.Ascending}, {"Column1.1", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Sorted headers",{"Column1.2"}),
    #"Transposed Table1" = Table.Transpose(#"Removed Columns")
in
    #"Transposed Table1"
```

You can also promote the headers, but note they would be labelled "Acres_1", "Acres_2", etc.